# Laws of $(B_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ and $(2B_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ : singular?

Tags: probability-theory

Are the laws of  $(B_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ and $(2B_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ mutually singular ?

More precisely, I know that the laws of two diffusion processes are mutually absolutely continuous if they share a common diffusion coefficient (application of Girsanov theorem).

However, I cannot understand why it is no more the case when they have different diffusion coefficients. This is why I ask the question about $(B_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ and $(2B_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$. If their laws are not mutually continuous, that would mean that one can find a measurable set of trajectories $\mathcal{A}$ for which $\mathbb{P}[(B_t)_{t\in [0,T]} \in \mathcal{A}]>0$ while $\mathbb{P}[(2B_t)_{t\in [0,T]} \in \mathcal{A}]=0$. The problem is : I don't know how to find such a set $\mathcal{A}$. Can anyone help me to understand this point ?

Thank you folks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer comes from the quadratic variation: $\mathsf P\{[B_t] = t\} = 1$ while $\mathsf P\{[2B_t] = 4t\} = 1$. In this case you can define $\mathcal A$ to be an event (subset of the space of processes with continuous trajectories, say $\omega$) as 
$$
\mathcal A_k = \{\omega:[\omega_t] = k^2t\}.
$$
Then $\mathsf P\{B_t\in \mathcal A_1\} = 1$ but $\mathsf P\{2B_t\in \mathcal A_1\} = 0$ and $\mathsf P\{B_t\in \mathcal A_2\} = 0$ but $\mathsf P\{2B_t\in \mathcal A_2\} = 1$.

See also [the related question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51090/change-of-time-or-change-of-measure) on MO.

Comment: @mellow: you're welcome. I mad some minor edits by the way

Comment: I am currently working on the same type of problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815265/girsanov-type-theorem-that-alters-the-variance-of-a-wiener-process). I came up with a valid Radon-Nikodym for a measure change that alters the variance, but the counter-example presented in your answer means that it doesn't produce an equivalent Wiener probability measure: just an equivalent CDF (PDF). I'd be interested in proving that the increments are not independent: if they are, then we must have a Brownian motion, which seems contradictory. Would you be interested in helping?

Comment: @JanStuller replied there

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [*law of the iterated logarithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Modulus_of_continuity) at $t=0$. For the set 
$$A:=\left\{\omega: \limsup_{t\to0} {|\omega_t|\over\sqrt{2t\log\log(1/t)}}=1\right\}$$
we have $\mu_B(A) = 1$, but $\mu_{2B}(A) = 0$. Here $\mu_B$ and $\mu_{2B}$ are the laws of Brownian motion and twice Brownian motion respectively.